# $X$ follows an exponential distribution, how to show that ${\rm E}[X \mid X > c] = {\rm E}[X] + c$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose that $X$ follows an Exponential Distribution, then by definition of its inherent memorylessness property:

$$
\Pr[X > x + c \mid X > c] = \Pr[X > x]
$$

I am wondering how this result translates to:

$$
{\rm E}[X \mid X > c] = {\rm E}[X] + c
$$

Where exactly does the $c$ come from if I were to integrate?

Comment: \begin{align}\mathsf E[X \mid X>c]&=\int_0^\infty \mathsf P[X>x \mid X>c] dx\\&=\int_0^c 1 \cdot dx+\int_0^\infty \mathsf P[X>x+c \mid X>c]dx\\&=c + \int_0^\infty \mathsf P[X>x]\\&=\mathsf E[X]+c\end{align}

Comment: And some herustic argument: $\mathsf P[X>x+c \mid X>c]=\mathsf P[X>x]$ means $X-c$ under condition $X>c$ has the same distribution as $X$ under no condition. So $\mathsf E[X-c \mid X>c]=\mathsf E[X]$.

Answer (score 3):

The exponential distribution is
$$
e^{-x/\mu}\ \frac{dx} \mu \text{ on } [0,\infty),
$$
from which it follows that
$$
\operatorname{E}(X) = \mu.
$$
What is the conditional distribution of $X$ given the event $X>c\,\text{?}$ We have
$$
\int_c^\infty e^{-x/\mu}\  \frac{dx} \mu = \int_{c\mu}^\infty e^{-u}\,du = e^{-c/\mu},
$$
and so
$$
\int_c^\infty e^{c/\mu} e^{-x/\mu} \  \frac{dx} \mu = 1.
$$
Therefore the conditional distribution of $X$ given $X>c$ is
$$
e^{-(x-c)/\mu}\, \frac{dx}\mu \text{ on } [c,\infty).
$$
This is just the original distribution shifted to the right by $c$ units. Thus the expected value must also be shifted to the right by $c$ units.